# How do you implement a custom login UI when using PKCE in auth0?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, auth0, pkce

I am setting up a login system in auth0 for a React Typescript application. Due to how the application works I am using the PKCE flow for authentication and authorization to get access tokens and refresh tokens. So far I have implemented the flow by adding a node js express server that fetches the access token and refresh token from auth0 once we have the authroization code after logging in through the /authroize endpoint on auth0. However the problem we have now is that we cant implement our custom UI onto the login page since when we hit the /authorize endpoint we are sent to the login page hosted at auth0. We would want to set up our own login form and send over the details to auth0 in order to fetch the authorization code. Is there a way to login through our own login page instead of using the one hosted by auth0, by for example hitting the right endpoint in their api to fetch an authorization code? The only other option I have seen is by changing the HTML under branding in the application dashboard but I have also read that auth0 does not recommend doing this.

I have also previously used the auth0 js SDK and there I was able to use our own custom page for login, however that SDK uses the implicit flow which does not issue refresh tokens and cannot therefore be used. In the other SPA sdk, you cant add your own UI for login since that redirects you to auth0 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you still use the Node.js server in addition to the SPA, you can ask the user for username and password, send it the Node.js server. Using the [Resource Owner Password](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#resource-owner-password) flow, the Node.js server can then request the access, refresh and ID tokens.

Please study the security implications carefully, in particular related to this authentication flow.

By implementing custom login UIs, you lose many things: hardened security of Auth0 servers, easy configuration of authentication methods without changing the application, use of ready-made Auth0 SDKs etc. I would carefully consider if it is worth it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! So if I would like the increased security from auth0 login but still use a custom user interface, the only other option would be to directly change the login widget in the auth0 dashboard? The thing is, the application that will be using this setup is fairly big so im thinking that the security risks are not worth it just for a custom design, even though this is the main thing we want to keep implemented. By any chance, do you know any other options to Auth0 that might fit our needs more?